# How to display items aligned?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

this is for sure a common question but text-align and display properties are not solving it, so i must have some mistake.
What should i do to display the 3 items in the same horizontal line?

```css
.contact__information {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1);
  padding-right: var(--mb-.75);
  align-items: right;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact section" id="contact">
  <h2 class="section__title">Contacte</h2>
  <span class="section__subtitle">Contacte para mais informações</span>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-phone contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Telemóvel</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">999-777-666</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-envelope contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Email</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">email.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-map-marker contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Morada</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">Portugal</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Define width 
Step 2: Locate parent to flex - `#contact` 
Step 3: `align-items: center;` makes all elements inline (aligned)
Step 4: `justify-content: space-evenly;` spaces all elements evenly. Using up extra space.

```css
#contact {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact section" id="contact">
  <h2 class="section__title">Contacte</h2>
  <span class="section__subtitle">Contacte para mais informações</span>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-phone contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Telemóvel</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">999-777-666</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-envelope contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Email</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">email.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-map-marker contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Morada</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">Portugal</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I got lost myself.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Feels like an opportunity for flex.  I added borders and padding just to make it obvious what was where and did some alignment you can customize as needed

```css
.contact.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;/* or column if you want the first two on top */
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

 .contact__information,
 .contact__information div { /*probably need a class for the div */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px lime;
padding:0.25rem;
}

.contact__information div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;/* or row if titles are in line with data */
  border: solid 1px pink;
}

.contact__title {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-self: center;
}

.contact__subtitle {
  border: solid #8d8dff 1px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact section" id="contact">
  <h2 class="section__title">Contacte</h2>
  <span class="section__subtitle">Contacte para mais informações</span>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-phone contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Telemóvel</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">999-777-666</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-envelope contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Email</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">email.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact__information">
    <i class="uil uil-map-marker contact__icon"></i>
    <div>
      <h3 class="contact__title">Morada</h3>
      <span class="contact__subtitle">Portugal</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```